# python variables between functions

Tags: python-2.7, variables, tkinter

I have a simple question. I have this 2 function but I don´t know how to get variables(VstredA1, VstredA2, VstredB1, VstredB2) from one function(Vstredvyp) to another(Vstredvysl). I try to use global variable but second function can´t read variables.

```
def Vstredvyp():
    vstredvyp = Tk.Tk()
    vstredvyp.title("Stred strany - Vypocet")
    vstredvyp.minsize(300, 240)
    vstredvyp.maxsize(600, 480)
    Tk.Label(vstredvyp, text="Zadejte souřadnice bodu:").pack()
    RvstredA1 = Tk.LabelFrame(vstredvyp, text="X souradnice A")
    RvstredA1.pack()
    RvstredA2 = Tk.LabelFrame(vstredvyp, text="Y souradnice A")
    RvstredA2.pack()
    RvstredB1 = Tk.LabelFrame(vstredvyp, text="X souradnice B")
    RvstredB1.pack()
    RvstredB2 = Tk.LabelFrame(vstredvyp, text="Y souradnice B")
    RvstredB2.pack()
    global VstredA1
    global VstredA2
    global VstredB1
    global VstredB2
    VstredA1 = Tk.Entry(RvstredA1)
    VstredA1.pack()
    VstredA2 = Tk.Entry(RvstredA2)
    VstredA2.pack()
    VstredB1 = Tk.Entry(RvstredB1)
    VstredB1.pack()
    VstredB2 = Tk.Entry(RvstredB2)
    VstredB2.pack()
    VstredA1 = Tk.IntType()
    VstredA2 = Tk.IntType()
    VstredB1 = Tk.IntType()
    VstredB2 = Tk.IntType()
    Tk.Button(vstredvyp, text="Ok", command=Vstredvysl).pack()
    Tk.Button(vstredvyp, text="Zpet", command=vstredvyp.destroy).pack()
    vstredvyp.mainloop()
    return


def Vstredvysl():
    vstredvysl = Tk.Tk()
    vstredvysl.title("Stred strany - Vysledek")
    vstredvysl.minsize(150, 120)
    vstredvysl.maxsize(300, 240)
    if VstredA1 == VstredB1 and VstredA2 == VstredB2:
        Tk.Label(vstredvysl, text="Nelze zjistit stred protoze body jsou totozne").pack()
        Tk.Button(vstredvysl, text="Zpet", command=vstredvysl.destroy).pack()
        vstredvysl.mainloop()
    else:
        Vstred1 = (VstredA1 + VstredB1) / 2
        Vstred2 = (VstredA2 + VstredB2) / 2
        Tk.Label(vstredvysl, text=Vstred1).pack()
        Tk.Label(vstredvysl, text=Vstred2).pack()
        Tk.Button(vstredvysl, text="Zpet", command=vstredvysl.destroy).pack()
        vstredvysl.mainloop()
    return
```

Comment: You should read some general Python tutorials. You can start [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions).  Also, please format your code correctly (what are those `**` doing?).

Comment: to create global varaibles you have to create them outside functions and later use keyword `global` inside functions to inform functions to use those external variables instead of creating local ones.

Comment: `tkinter` needs only one `mainloop()` because two `mainloop()` makes problems with values in `StringVar()` and widgets. And it should has only one `Tk()` window. To create second window use `Toplevel()`

Comment: what is `IntType()` ? `tkinter doesn't have `IntType()` but `IntVar()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example with global variable and two windows.

It uses only one `mainloop()` and `Toplevel()` to create second window.

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def main():
    #inform function to use external/global variable
    global int_var # only if you will use `=` to change value

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Root")

    # change global variable using `=`
    int_var = tk.IntVar()

    # use global variable
    e = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=int_var)
    e.pack()

    tk.Button(root, text="Second", command=second).pack(fill='x')
    tk.Button(root, text="Exit", command=root.destroy).pack(fill='x')

    root.mainloop()


def second():
    #inform function to use external/global variable
    #global int_var # only if you will use `=` to change value

    other = tk.Toplevel()
    other.title("Other")

    # use global variable
    l = tk.Label(other, textvariable=int_var)
    l.pack()

    tk.Button(other, text="Exit", command=other.destroy).pack()

    #other.wait_window()

# --- start ---

# create global variable
int_var = None

main()
```